# TFS Server keeps deleting content in old existing workspace, and still retains old local code modifications in new workspace

Tags: tfs, version-control, revision, source-control-explorer

I'm trying to get a fresh copy of the source code from the TFS server, and I already have an existing workspace.  However, I want to leave the existing workspace as it is because I have some local code modifications that I want to keep in the existing workspace.

I just want a brand new workspace that will have a fresh copy of the source code from the TFS server

In TFS Source Control Explorer, I righted-clicked on the source control folder, and I navigated along the following options.
[image]

However, when I try to do remap,
1)  TFS will delete a lot the content in my existing workspace
2), and furthermore he creates the new workspace but the new worskpace some how retains my existing local code modifications.

a) How do I maintain my existing workspace with the local code modification intact?
b) How do I create a new workspace in such a way that I get a fresh copy of the source code from the TFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to **Add a new workpace** but not remap.

Basically remap means the workspace existing there and needs map to another local folder, as a workspace can only be mapped to one local folder, when you select `Remove Mapping...` by default it will remove the contents and **only keep the changed files there** which not be checked in yet. Then map the existing workspace to a new local folder. It's the expected behavior.

Based on your requirement, you just need to **Add a new workspace and map to a new local folder, and keep the existing workspace there.**

***To add a new workspace:***

From the Team Explorer home page --> Under Solution --> Workspace --> Manage Workspace --> Add. (Refer to [Add, edit, or remove a workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/create-work-workspaces#add-edit-or-remove-a-workspace) for details)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm been really busy at work. will respond soon.